# How to prevent TextToSpeech from stopping during rotation

Tags: android, text-to-speech

My app is implementing Text-to-Speech that is working well. But when I rotate my phone, the dictation stops itself.

You have to know that I use two different layout for landscape/portrait mode.

How should I handle the screen rotation ?
1) With `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` // I don't think it's the best way
2) With something else?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically have 2 options:

1) Handle the orientation change yourself. Usually this is pretty easy. You just need to implement `onConfigurationChange()` and in there you can just rebuild the layout by calling `setContentView()`. Be aware that this will recreate all your UI views so you will have to call `findViewById()` and reset onClickListeners again for all views that you need to keep track of.

2) Ensure that the TTS instance doesn't get shutdown on orientation change. You can do this either by passing the TTS instance from one instance of the activity to the next OR keep track of the TTS instance in a static variable (if you do this you need to make sure that you call `shutdown()` on it at the appropriate time, not in `onDestroy()` of your activity.

Comment: With option #2, if I don't shutdown the TTS instance in onDestroy, the TTS engine will continue to speak even if the user hit the back button in order to hide the app. Right?

And with option #1, I don't know how to retrieve what the user typed in the EditText after calling setContentView() again. Could you help me at this point?

Comment: With option #1, you just need to save all the user input from your views in onPause(). Then, in onResume() you just copy the values back into the views.

Comment: It worked out, thanks, but in a different way (with onConfigurationChanged). However with option #1, I've had many troubles. For example, if the user is typing something, and you rotate the phone, the EditText won't directly get the focus, and the displayed keyboard won't match the new EditText one.

Comment: Well, if that isn't working for you, just try option #2. You may have to trap certain key presses in order to stop the speech when the user performs certain actions, but that's all up to you!

Comment: Ok, I will probably opte for option #2, but how to stop the diction when the user returns to the home screen (I have to call shutdown() in onStop() but it will stop the diction when the user rotates the screen). How do I prevent this from happening? Thank you so much!

Comment: You could try calling `getChangingConfigurations()` in `onStop()`. This may be an effective way of determining that the activity is being stopped due to a configuration change. Another option would be to start a timer thread in `onStop()` for maybe 3 or 5 seconds. When the timer expires, you can stop the TTS. If, however, your activity gets recreated, it should cancel the timer in `onCreate()` to prevent the TTS from being shut down.

Comment: getChangingConfigurations() is definitely the best way. Thank you, I didn't know this method. I'll try to make it work tonight.

Answer (score 2):

There are several steps to enabling the TTS to continue working on rotation, without needing to handle the configuration changes in your app. The steps include:

- Make the TTS variable static

  `private static TextToSpeech tts;`
- Only initialize it once, if it's null

  `if (tts == null) { ... }`
- Initialize the TTS object using the Application Context

  `tts = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), this);`

Here's a snapshot of my experimental app that incorporates these elements http://code.google.com/p/android-tts-experiments/source/detail?r=b879fd1042151cbebc736b89a9fb660c895081ea I've managed to test it on various android devices and android versions. Sometimes the TTS seems to hesitate slightly on rotation on my older, less powerful devices, however it continues speaking the text it's being given to say and queued messages are retained in the queue and spoken once the current text has been spoken completely by the TTS engine.